# Calling paintEvent() from a class in pyqt4 python

Tags: python, pyqt4, paintevent

I have written a class to display rectangles (the cell class). I would like to have functions inside the class to call in another class (i.e. calling `cell.paintEvent(self,event)` and `cell.drawRectangles(self,qp)` in a function defined in a Window class). Unfortunately, I do not know how to call these functions in another class (i.e. Window) as they both require arguments (i.e. `event` and `pq`) and I do not know what to pass on to them.

Here is the code for my cell class:

```
class cell(object):
    def __init__(self, c, x, y, w, h, active,flux_val,index):

        self.c1 = c
        self.c2 = c
        self.c3 = 255
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        self.index = index
        self.active = active
        self.flux_val = flux_val
        self.isChecked = False
        self.isHit = False

    def paintEvent(self, e):

        qp = QtGui.QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        self.drawRectangles(qp)
        qp.end()

    def drawRectangles(self, qp):

        color = self.c2
        #qp.setPen(color)

        qp.setBrush(color)
        qp.drawRect(self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h)
```

Here is the part of the code (specifically `def.initiate(self)`) where I want to instantiate an array of cell objects ( which I can easily do) and then call its relevant display functions (i.e. `cell.paintEvent(self,event)` and `cell.drawRectangles(self,qp)`, which I still have not figured out how to do):

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np


class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 1000, 800)
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQT tuts!")
        self.initiate()
        self.show()

    def initiate(self):
        #initiate an array of cell objects
        #Call their display functions (or any other relevant class functions)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `paintEvent` method must be overwritten by the classes that inherit from QWidget. You can implement the function `drawRectangles` but you must invoke the `paintEvent` method using `update()` method.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class cell(object):
    def __init__(self, c, x, y, w, h):
        self.color = c
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = w
        self.h = h

    def drawRectangles(self, qp):
        qp.setBrush(self.color)
        qp.drawRect(self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h)


class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 1000, 800)
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQT tuts!")
        self.cells = []

        now = QtCore.QTime.currentTime()
        QtCore.qsrand(now.msec())
        self.createCells()

    def createCells(self):
        for i in range(100):
            self.cells.append(cell(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.qrand() % 256,
                                                QtCore.qrand() % 256,
                                                QtCore.qrand() % 256),
                                   QtCore.qrand() % self.width(), QtCore.qrand() % self.height(),
                                   QtCore.qrand() % 40, QtCore.qrand() % 40))
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        for c in self.cells:
            c.drawRectangles(qp)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Well, you would need to import the cell object. To that you need to

```
from yourFileNameWithCellObject import cell
```

To initialize a cell, you simply need to do

```
newCell = cell(args_here)
```

or to make the `newCell` as a part of `self` (Window)

```
self.newCell = cell(args_here)
```

To call methods in the cell object is quite simple.

```
self.newCell.paintEvent(args_here)
```

Comment: Actually all of the code is in one file. I have already defined a cell object (i.e. test = cell(a,b,c,....)) and then tried test.paintEvent() in the initiate(). But I am prompted that paintEvent() needs an argument and it does not work. I do not know what to do when I am supposed to pass it an 'event' argument. I did define a function is the cell class called def pr(self), which would only print a string. I could easily call that function (i.e. test.pr(), would print the string). Probably if paintEvent was a void, I could just say test.paintEvent() and it would draw the shape for me.

Comment: @Jamycodes well if you have a function called `pr`, then pass in the event argument `pr` like `cell.paintEvent(cell.pr)`. But from your code posted above, I don't see where the `e` in `paintEvent(self, e)` is being used.

Comment: That is a good point. I can not see it either. I am taking my lead from this example which uses the same functions, but not having in an object class like me. I can not see where the "e" as an argument is being inputed in the function:
Here is the link:
[http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/drawing/]

Comment: Sorry for late reply and bad link. The answer provided is spot on, nonetheless I am reposting the link and make sure it is not broken: